# Select SVG item by class in JS (Observer)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to select an svg item using an observer. The goal is to display the svg item once it enters the view window. I want the animation to play only when it enters the viewport. I have set the initial `display` property to `none` - and have created a class to set the `display` property to `block`. Manually adding the class in inspector works. I want to add the animation class `front-social-start` to be added to the class list once in viewport.

Please help, I'm surviving on nothing but caffeine because of this little bugger XD

HTML

```
<div class="radial-graph-container">
            <svg width="200" height="200" class="chart-container">
              <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" class="back" fill="none" />

<!-- The below circle is the one I want to select -->

              <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" class="front-social" fill="none" />
              <g class="graph-center-txt">
                <text
                  x="100"
                  y="100"
                  alignment-baseline="central"
                  text-anchor="middle"
                  id="percentage-social-media-usage"
                >
                  0%
                </text>
              </g>
            </svg>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.back {
  stroke: #101114;
  stroke-width: 10;
}

.front-social {
  stroke: #e96f31;
  stroke-width: 15;
  stroke-dasharray: 395.84;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: fill 1.7s reverse;
  display: none;
}

.front-social-start {
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
const el = document.querySelector('.font-social');
          const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
            // Loop over the entries
          entries.forEach(entry => {
            // If the element is visible
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          //   Add the animation class
          el.classList.add('front-social-start');
            }
          });
        });

        observer.observe(document.getElementsByClassName('.front-social'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added unique Id to `radial-graph-container` i.e. `id="radial-graph-containersm"`

Hides entire `div` and displays when it enters the viewport. A solid compromise.

Changed observer to add class to item based on ID.

CSS

```
.radial-graph-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 2.4rem;
  display: none;
}

.radial-graph-start {
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
          const graphSm = document.querySelector('#radial-graph-containersm');
          const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
            // Loop over the entries
          entries.forEach(entry => {
            // If the element is visible
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          //   Add the animation class
          graphSm.classList.add('radial-graph-start');
            }
          });
        });
```

Sorry, funny how things work out - struggled for hours only to figure out a solution 20 minutes after asking for help. Ahhhhh the joys of coding...